# Feeling and Looking Young

Tags: exercise, health, home-exercise, age

I am software programmer and I do lots of research like software/database architecture most of the time. I recently got comment from my friends that I am looking older than my age. I am 28 and I am said to look around 38. I came home and had a look in the mirror and saw that I have receding hair lines , big beard and unhealthy face. I don't exercise much. I am doing my MBA and hold a full time job where I have lot of responsibility.

My college are ending in a month and I will have more time. How can I revive my health and youth? Is there any suggestion to remain healthy internally and externally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A healthy diet means a healthy body, I'm not saying to start a diet, but to eat healthier, more greens, fruits, vegetables, less processed/fast foods. Hair loss can be related to stress, and judging by your work, study field I'm assuming you can be put under a lot of it, B-complex can help you out lowering down your stress levels, there's also some shampoos and conditioners that can help you making your hair roots stronger.

I know this is gonna a long shot (judging by your field) but try to rest well, sleeping is a **big** factor in your overall health. A well rested body, means a well rested mind.

As for your workouts, set a goal; do you want to lose weight? do you want to gain muscle? do you just wanna be fit? After setting your *body goals* is when you can actually draw a workout plan.